# Choose rows based on a range of time in different dates

Tags: python, pandas

I use this code to select rows between two times within a day:

```
s2 = s1[s1['OnsetTime'].between(start_sleep, end_sleep)]
```

However, if the end time is in the next day, all rows were removed

```
end_sleep = pd.to_datetime('05:00:00').time()
start_sleep = pd.to_datetime('21:00:00').time()
s2 = s1[s1['OnsetTime'].between(start_sleep, end_sleep)]
```

Could you please advise? Thanks.

Comment: Please share a sample of dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use negation:

```
s2 = s1[~s1['OnsetTime'].between(end_sleep,start_sleep)]
```